# Killing a Cloud Foundry Instance

Tags: cloud, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

When killing a cloud foundry instance of a broker app does it restart the same one or does it take a round robin approach?

I have 3 instances on my broker app and when I send a curl delete call to an instance, it will make an attempt to bring that instance back up. If I continue to kill instance 0, does it kill the same instance every single time or does instance #1 become #0 and kill that one etc etc?

Answer (score 4):

If you have an application that it is scaled to three instances and you terminate one instance (using `cf curl /v2/apps/<guid>/instances/0 -X 'DELETE'`), that instance will still exist with the same index. You can see this using the output from `cf app`:

```
     state     since                    cpu    memory          disk          
#0   down      1970-01-01 01:00:00 AM   0.0%   0 of 0          0 of 0
#1   running   2016-08-30 07:42:23 PM   0.1%   8.1M of 128M    12.1M of 1G
#2   running   2016-08-30 07:42:24 PM   0.0%   11.4M of 128M   12.1M of 1G
```

So to answer your question, there is no re-ordering of instance IDs and sending multiple requests to kill one particular instance does just affect one.

Comment: Could you please tell me what is <guid> in the command? I tried to run this with application name as guid but it failed. How can I get guid?

Comment: @AJavaCoder GUID is the application name ID.

Comment: A GUID of an application is not the name of the application. You can get it using "cf app <app-name> --guid" command.